# Package Receiving heart rate data from a flutter smartwatch

Tags: flutter, wear-os, apple-watch, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am looking for a package that can fit me in a flutter that will sync between smart watches like Samsung watch or Apple Watch. I want to get heart rate data from them. Anyone know of such a package or idea to communicate with the watch?

Comment: You can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76464852/12555686

Answer (score 3):

At present all of wear, tizen, and watch os have different mechanisms for obtaining this data natively, all of which would need a flutter MethodChannel mapping to expose to the flutter side. For wear you can use the  [wearable_communicator](https://github.com/gardyna/wearable_communicator) plugin for communicating via the data layer, but I’m not aware of any equivalent for the other two. Alternatively, you could publish this data from the watch to something like an MQTT broker and use an MQTT client on the flutter app to obtain the readings.