# How to send data from smartwatch to Flutter app

Tags: flutter, sony-smartwatch

I am looking for a method to get data(heart rate) from a smartwatch(wear/tizen/watch) and read them using a Flutter app. Anyone know of such a package or idea to communicate with the smartwatch and a Flutter APP PLZ?

Comment: What you are looking for is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76464852/12555686

Answer (score 4):

You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67943555/15212468) answer which is pretty much what you were asking.

It says that, by now, you can do it only for wear thanks to [this](https://github.com/gardyna/wearable_communicator) package.
Here's an [example](https://github.com/gardyna/wearable_communicator#recieve-message-example) for receiving messages:

```dart
// msg is either a Map<String, dynamic> or a string (make sure to check for that when using the library)
WearableListener.listenForMessage((msg) {
  print(msg);
});
```