# How to Connect a Smartwatch to a Flutter App and retrieve steps details from the watch?

Tags: flutter, dart, wear-os, tracking, android-bluetooth

I'm working on a Flutter app and I want to establish a connection with a smartwatch to exchange step(tracking) data and control some features. I've done some research(Android & iOS), but I'm not sure where to start or which libraries to use for this task.

Any code examples, tutorials, or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send data from smartwatch to Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70556192/how-to-send-data-from-smartwatch-to-flutter-app)

Comment: Not working with this reference link @RaSha

Answer (score 1):

I found this package which may help you retrieve data from a smartwatch:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_smart_watch

Let me know if you find out more on this topic!